# Is there any way to get a collection of all the javax.sql.DataSource that are configured as beans within a Spring Application/Container?

Tags: java, xml, database, spring, dao

Given that one can construct a datasource bean as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url2}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource3" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url3}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Is there a way to get a collection of all these datasources without having to explicitly reference the beans through their identifier? e.g. getBean("dataSource3"). Does the container or the application context offer any help here?

In essence given a configuration file with all beans already defined, in spring is it possible to implement?

```
Collection<DataSource> getAllRegisteredDataSources();
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Just add field with type `List<DataSource>` to the bean in which you want this. Also I suggest you take a look at the API as there a quite more methods then only `getBean("<name-of-bean")`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are two approaches you can take to solving this problem.

The first approach, basic approach, would be to create a master configuration and auto-wire additional configurations and through the auto-wired context you can construct the collection of Datasources

```
  @Configuration
  @Import({ DataSourceAConfig.class }) // Import additional configuration files as required
  public class MasterConfig {

          @Autowired DataSourceAConfig dataSourceAConfigContext; 

            @Bean public List<DataSource> getAllDataSources(){
                 DataSource dataSourceA = dataSourceAConfigContext.getDataSourceBean()
                 // Add data in sequentially way, one after the other 
                return Arrays.asList(dataSourceA);
     }
  }
```

The second approach; the approach that I recommend would be to have a look at the actuator services that are shipped with Spring boot applications, in particular those around the metrics.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

They give additional information beyond the number of active data sources; including resource utilisation and health checks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent , what I was looking for really! Thanks!